# Why Oracle SQL Flash Recover Area is blank?

Tags: oracle, backup, data-recovery

I get 0 rows in the results I use
`SELECT * from V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`

V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST is a default table name for the oracle Flash recovery area.
Does this mean that a Backup never happens on this platform or Flash recovery area name is different from the default? If yes, then how can I locate the Flash Recovery area on Oracle Database if yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST` shows target OS or ASM directories, as specified in the  `db_recovery_area_dir` initialization parameter, which are designated to contain flash recovery area files. If there is nothing visible in the table, confirm the setting of the initialization parameter. If both are null/empty, then there is no Flash Recovery Area defined for the database.

```
select * from v$recovery_file_dest;

NAME  SPACE_LIMIT SPACE_USED SPACE_RECLAIMABLE NUMBER_OF_FILES     CON_ID
----- ----------- ---------- ----------------- --------------- ----------
+RECO 1.3980E+10  8989442048                 0               5          0

show parameter db_recovery

NAME                       TYPE        VALUE  
-------------------------- ----------- ------ 
db_recovery_file_dest      string      +RECO  
db_recovery_file_dest_size big integer 13332M
```